# Error: Module should export a function: i18next

Tags: javascript, plugins, i18next, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt js application, I installed [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/):

```
npm install --save-dev i18next
```

Then  whenever I add it to the plugin array in **nuxt.config.js** as the [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/) suggests:

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    vendor: ['i18next']
  }
}
```

I get this error when I start the sever (`npm run dev`)

```
 ERROR  Nuxt error

  Error: Module should export a function: i18next

  - module.js:127 ModuleContainer.addModule
    [begueradj]/[nuxt]/lib/core/module.js:127:13

  - utils.js:96 promise.then
    [begueradj]/[nuxt]/lib/common/utils.js:96:43


  - next_tick.js:189 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7

  - module.js:696 Function.Module.runMain
    module.js:696:11

  - bootstrap_node.js:204 startup
    bootstrap_node.js:204:16

  - bootstrap_node.js:625 
    bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Why does this happen? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The `vendor` array is used on Nuxt.js 1.x to help Webpack 3 to optimize build. It's not used to import a lib.

(nb: since Nuxt.js 2.x, that `vendor` config is deprecated and can be removed)

---

To import an external lib, you have create a custom Vue.js plugin and to declare it in the `nuxt.config.js` in the `plugins` array (https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/)

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['~/plugins/your-cutom-plugins']
}
```

or,

you can import your external lib in your component/page/middleware/plugin file to use it directly:

```
<script>
import i18next from 'i18next'
​
i18next.init({ 
   ...
)
</script>
```

(nb: prefer use `install --save` because "i18next" is not only used on dev, but on production too)